# curvature and torsion information from the 3d points

Tags: differential-geometry

Hi I have some n points in 3d space and I want to connect them to form a 3d curve. I want to know a method of finding its torsion and curvature along its arclength.
Any references or example would help me. The curve can be of any arbitrary smooth shape.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? As you've described the problem, this curve will not be unique

Comment: I want a function of curvature and torsion along its arclength. I know the curve cannot be easily parametrized to  plug into the formula of torsion and curvature. for example if I am given a figure 8 knot I want to find its curvature and torsion.

Comment: I see... in which case what is the importance of the $n$ points? Do you have an expression for the function of the curve?

Comment: thats just an example. I dont have function of any curve(something complex like such knot) which comes from joining the n points using a spline. In that case how to get curvature and torsion info

Comment: For the torsion, you need your points to have an orientation, otherwise it's ill-defined. I think you can only define the torsion if you have a frame of reference attached to each point.